# QDebug string array display

Tags: string, qt, operators

Here is a simple domo:

```
string strList[4] = {"Blue", "Red", "Yellow"};
qDebug()<<"strList element : "<<strList[1];

error: C2678: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'QDebug' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

What is the problem for string display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "string" class isn't recognized by Qt's Debug module. You need to be using QString and in this case, you probably want QStringList (which is equivalent to QList ).

```
QStringList strList;
strList << "Blue" << "Red" << "Yellow";
qDebug() << "strList element : " << strList[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

qDebug doesnt take strings but can handle very good the "c- strings"

instead of doing:

```
qDebug()<<"strList element : "<<strList[1];
```

do:

```
string strList[4] = {"Blue", "Red", "Yellow"};
qDebug()<<"strList element : "<<strList[1].c_str();
```